# Django Python: Can't get part of string

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to output the text of a thread, but I don't want to display the entire text of the thread. I just want to display a small preview of it (the first 100 characters). The problem is I get a `TemplateSyntaxError` when I try to substring it.

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <p>Title: {{ post.title }}</p>
        <p>Posted on: {{ post.created_on }}</p>
        <p>User: {{ post.author }}</p>
        <p>{{ {% post.text[0:100] %} | safe }}</p>
    </div>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the error:

```
Could not parse some characters: |{% post.text[0:100] %}| | safe
```

Comment: Django template language is not Python, it's a different language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You the django [slice](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter to emulate slicing:

`{{ some_list|slice:":2" }}`

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this,

```
{{ post.text|safe|slice:":100" }}
```

> slice: Returns a slice of the list.
>
> Uses the same syntax as Python’s list slicing. See
>   http://www.diveintopython3.net/native-datatypes.html#slicinglists for
>   an introduction.